# Can network packet corruption affect only one server process out of many that are talking to the database?

Tags: networking

### Context

We saw sporadic `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` errors from MySQL servers over the course of 4 hours yesterday. The errors haven't happened since then.

Strangely, SQL statements seemed to have been corrupted: a random character or more shifted by 2 bytes backwards or forwards. For example, `"Unknown table 'erades'"` for a query against a `grades` table. This wasn't limited to table names: column names, SQL keywords, and values were all affected in those queries.

#### The error

A sample of error messages:

> `.` -> `,` : Table '[database name].id' doesn't exist: SELECT [..] FROM [..] INNER JOIN [..] ON [..] = `[table name]`.`id` ..
>   `` ` `` -> `b` : Incorrect table name 'topic_setsb ON ': SELECT [..] FROM [..] INNER JOIN `topic_sets` ON ...
>   `s` -> `q` : Unknown column 'aqsigned_[redacted]' in 'field list'
>   `U` -> `W` : You have an error in your SQL syntax; [..] near 'NWLL GROUP BY ...
>   `8` -> `:` : You have an error in your SQL syntax; [..] near ':887)' at line 1: SELECT [..]  WHERE [..] IN (48846, 48901, 48887)

Since MySQL will likely report only the first error in the statement, I couldn't tell the exact number of corruptions per statement. The full SQL query included in the message seems to be [a copy of the statement held on the client side](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/95bfea3d430187fda31caea44ded0a8ab606525d/ext/mysql2/statement.c#L47), and there was no corruption in that portion of the message.

In some cases, I couldn't tell which character could have been corrupted from the error message, such as "the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" and not all corruptions may have been about byte-shifts. This might be from unprintable characters or there might have been insertion/deletions of characters.

There was a *somewhat* fixed pattern in the way statements got corrupted, but there seemed to be no clear-cut rule. e.g. There would be 10-20 occurrences of a few patterns where the same statement was corrupted in the same way, but the position of corruptions vary among those patterns.

The error log I can obtain from the RDS console is empty. There was no AWS service degradation reported for the time period.

There were a total of 143 errors reported to our exception tracking tool. They originated from 4 Passenger workers, 2 on the same EC2 instance and the other two on another EC2 instance. Distribution of error counts across these workers: 1, 41, 42, 50. This is about 0.001% of the total requests served during the 4 hours this happened.

For each worker, errors happened in trickles: each reported these errors for around 5 minutes, with 1-2 errors happening every few seconds to 2-3 minutes - aside from the one that had only 1 error.

Some queries were against the master database and some were against the replica database.

#### Environment and other facts:

- AWS RDS MySQL 5.6.39
- AWS EC2 instances c4.4xlarge. There were 15+ instances serving the same website at the time.
- Apache 2, mpm module: event
- Passenger 5.3.3, concurrency model: process. Typically there are 30+ worker processes in a single EC2 instance.
- Rails 4.2.10, database pool size: 2.
- MySQL client library: mysql2 0.4.10
- Ruby 2.3.7

Timeline

```
instance A launch           2018-11-13 12:00 UTC
instance A process P errors 2018-11-13 13:40-13:43 UTC
instance A process Q errors 2018-11-13 14:22-14:26 UTC
instance A shutdown         2018-11-13 20:00 UTC
instance B launch           2018-11-13 15:00 UTC
instance B process R errors 2018-11-13 15:39-15:40 UTC
instance B process S errors 2018-11-13 17:39-17:43 UTC
instance B shutdown         2018-11-13 23:00 UTC
```

### Possible cause

One acquaintance admitted they saw the same kind of error in AWS on the same day, and referred to [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKg9RI6IkV8) <sup>[1]</sup> about network-level data corruption: it talks about how network switches recompute the Ethernet CRC of a packet when rerouting and corruption during the rerouting process may result in a "valid" CRC, and how TCP checksum also has a loophole. ([Textual notes by kevinchen.co](https://kevinchen.co/blog/bang-bang-con-notes-2017/)).

<sub>[1] !!Con 2017: Corruption in the Data Center! TCP can fail to keep your data safe! by Evan Jones</sub>

Their recommendation was to use TLS for all communication, as the TLS layer will fail to decypt the corrupted bytes.

I also found [this page](http://noahdavids.org/self_published/CRC_and_checksum.html) that describes the limitation of CRC and checksum. There's a similar-looking error in this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/215266/queries-passed-to-sql-server-are-getting-corrupted) and the cause there was also network-related.

I'm increasingly convinced that the errors are caused by something faulty at the network level.

### Question

Does the Ethernet / TCP theory agree with the erroneous behavior I described? I'm not sure if it's possible for just one process at a time to see this error, although I suppose it can happen if a switch decides to handle packets differently based on the source - destination port pairs, as each connection will be using a different port.

I'd be happy to reframe the question if this is actually an XY question.

Note: I've posted a request to [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=293448) for confirmation / investigation that this was something from AWS's infrastructure. Here, in serverfault, I'm interested in learning about the plausibility of the hypothesis and how it can exhibit the behavior I saw (or not).

Comment: I'd assume its an error in the client side of the mysql protocol implementation. Network errors generally get caught and checked/dropped before they end up in a user application. Can you reduce to a pool size of 1 on one instance to see if that make it immune to error?

Comment: @danblack I could make the change but it'll be hard to tell if it made a difference since the errors didn't happen regularly enough and aren't happening at all right now. The app has been using the same client library version for 7 months and this is the first time. The client side theory also wouldn't explain well why it happened on two (and only two) servers at around the same time. The theory that some network hardware that handles networking centrally was at fault feels more plausible, but yeah, I'm not sure how plausible it is for the non-general case to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's within the realm of plausibility, hard to conclude anything. The bit flips you listed are consistent at an 8bit alignment. Although it'd be interesting to see the entire message as there'd (likely) have to be other flips in the network frames as well in order to foil CRCs/checksums.

In terms of "only some workers on the same machine reports errors" it could be - load across the workers aren't equal, it's simply an effect of number of bytes of traffic generated per process, or if the workers do keep persistent connections, you just lost the game of chance in path selection. i.e. the workers reporting errors happen to have connections that hash onto the bad link in the case of multiple active links somewhere along the way. (See it's not uncommon to hash (srcip,srcport,dstip,dstport) for link selection, both for L2 (lacp/bond) and L3 (ECMP)). It is possible with shorter lived connections as well, although it's now moving towards less likely. It's also entirely possible that AWS has more esoteric path selection for their network as well which could account for it.

I'd typically be a bit gnarly and look for other corroborating evidence, like checksum error counters from the os, nic and switches/routers, although I'd be inclined to say the split you have with some instances have no problems, whereas others do have problems as good corroborating evidence.

Flip pattern:

```
00101110 .
00101100 ,
00000010 xor

01100000 `
01100010 b
00000010 xor

01110011 s
01110001 q
00000010

01010101 U
01010111 W
00000010 xor

00111000 8
00111010 :
00000010 xor
```